# Bash $PATH is caching every modification

Tags: scripting, path, bash

How to clear the cache of $PATH in BASH. Every time I modify the $PATH, the former modifications are conserved too! So my $PATH is already one page :-), and it bothers me to work, because it points to some not right places (because every modification is being appended in the end of the $PATH variable). Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Based on the comment to SiegeX it looks like what you really want is to remove individual parts of `$PATH`. Please reformulate the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> because every modification is being
>   appended in the end of the $PATH
>   variable

Take a close look at where you are setting `$PATH`, I bet it looks something like this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/some/new/dir:/another/newdir:"
```

Having `$PATH` in the new assignment gives you the appending behavior you don't want.

Instead do this:

```
PATH="/some/new/dir:/another/newdir:"
```

#### Update

If you want to strip `$PATH` of all duplicate entries but still maintain the original order then you can do this:

```
PATH=$(awk 'BEGIN{ORS=":";RS="[:\n]"}!a[$0]++' <<<"${PATH%:}")
```

Comment: But if I do in the second way, then the other variables that were in the $PATH will be deleted. And I may override some important (may be system) commands!

Comment: @Narek your question says you ***don't*** want to preserve previous modifications but your comment says you ***do***, you can't have it both ways! Are you asking how do I alter $PATH such that if the new directory you are about to add already exists, it won't be duplicated?

Comment: @Narek see my updated to do what I mentioned in the comment above

Comment: OK, I see my question confused you. Imagine, that there is a variable $A, which is and env var and also exportPATH=$PATH:$A. Now when I change the $A form $OLD_A to $NEW_A, close and reopen the terminal window, I see that my $PATH is $PATH:$OLD_A:$NEW_A, but I want to have only $PATH:$NEW_A. This is the problem.

Comment: @Narek: that doesn't make sense, as environment variables (both PATH and A) are separate for each terminal session.  If you open a new terminal window, it has its own PATH no matter what you did to PATH is some other session.  It sounds like you're actually adding things to your ~/.profile (or ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login) file, which *is* run for each new terminal session.

Comment: No I do not. I add into .bashrc, but I don't know the settigs at my work place we use that may lead to this kind of behaviour. What could be the reason?

Comment: @SiegeX, I don't understand awk... would you mind explaining in detail what the awk script does? Could you modify it so that the final result does not have two consecutive : chars, and that the result does not end with :? Thanks

Comment: Hey @SiegeX, do you realize you've added ":" to the end of the value, which effectively puts "." in your path, even if it wasn't there before?  This is [a big no-no](https://serverfault.com/questions/776187/security-implications-of-using-relative-paths-in-the-path-enivronmental-variable#answer-776198) for any security conscious person.  Perhaps you could fix that?  It's creating security problems for people who copy-paste your recipe.

Answer (score 2):

```
PATH=$(echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ':')
```

Once in a while execute the above command. It will tidy up your PATH variable by removing any duplication.

-Cheers

PS: Warning: This will reorder the Paths in PATH variable. And can have undesired effects !!

Comment: Unfortunately, it also sorts the entries alphabetically, which will mess up the precedence...

Comment: @Gordon see my updated answer on how to do this in a 1-liner and preserve order

Answer (score 1):

When I'm setting my PATH, I usually use this script - which I last modified in 1999, it seems (but use daily on all my Unix-based computers).  It allows me to add to my PATH (or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or CDPATH, or any other path-like variable) and eliminate duplicates, and trim out now unwanted values.

#### Usage

```
export PATH=$(clnpath /important/bin:$PATH:/new/bin /old/bin:/debris/bin)
```

The first argument is the new path, built by any technique you like.  The second argument is a list of names to remove from the path (if they appear - no error if they don't).  For example, I have up to about five versions of the software I work on installed at any given time.  To switch between versions, I use this script to adjust both PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to pick up the correct values for the version I'm about to start using, and remove the values of the version I'm no longer using.

#### Code

```
:   "@(#)$Id: clnpath.sh,v 1.6 1999/06/08 23:34:07 jleffler Exp $"
#
#   Print minimal version of $PATH, possibly removing some items

case $# in
0)  chop=""; path=${PATH:?};;
1)  chop=""; path=$1;;
2)  chop=$2; path=$1;;
*)  echo "Usage: `basename $0 .sh` [$PATH [remove:list]]" >&2
    exit 1;;
esac

# Beware of the quotes in the assignment to chop!
echo "$path" |
${AWK:-awk} -F: '#
BEGIN   {   # Sort out which path components to omit
            chop="'"$chop"'";
            if (chop != "") nr = split(chop, remove); else nr = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= nr; i++)
                omit[remove[i]] = 1;
        }
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    {
        x=$i;
        if (x == "") x = ".";
        if (omit[x] == 0 && path[x]++ == 0)
        {
            output = output pad x;
            pad = ":";
        }
    }
    print output;
}'
```

#### Commentary

The ':' is an ancient way of using `/bin/sh` (originally the Bourne shell - now as often Bash) to run the script.  If I updated it, the first line would become a shebang.  I'd also not use tabs in the code.  And there are ways to get the 'chop' value set that do not involve as many quotes:

```
awk -F: '...script...' chop="$chop"
```

But it isn't broken, so I haven't fixed it.

Comment: Hey @Jon, Out of curiosity, does your script's output differ from the 1-liner that I put in my updated answer?

Comment: @SiegeX: Yes, they differ.  Mine can remove components from a PATH that you ask to be removed; yours just deals with dups (which mine also does).  So, in my example in the answer, the /old/bin and /debris/bin entries are removed from PATH by my script, but not by yours.

Comment: Aha. Well in that case try [THIS](http://codepad.org/JWoGBf6k) on for size; it should be functionally equivalent to your script.  If you run that with no params it just removes dupes, otherwise it removes the paths you pass in as well as removes dupes. i.e `./clnpath.sh` just removes dupes and `./clnpath.sh /home/jonathan /usr/bin` will remove dupes and take out those two dirs. Although important to note it will *not* remove `/usr/bin/baz` due to the anchoring.

Comment: @SiegeX: nearly...my shell script (shown above) works with CDPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH which yours does not easily do - though it could be modified to do so if you changed the interface.  I'm not ready to discard my shell script - or the Perl script I also have on some machines, which tests that the directories exist before adding them to the output (circa 2007).  Having the script accept multiple 'remove' names is fine; I chose not to do that, but it is a valid alternative design.

Comment: Gotcha, was more of an exercise for me to see how I could add that functionality with as little additional code as possible, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

When adding entries to PATH, you should check to see if they're already there.  Here's what I use in my .bashrc:

```
pathadd() {
    if [ -d "$1" ] && [[ ":$PATH:" != *":$1:"* ]]; then
        PATH="$PATH:$1"
fi
}
pathadd /usr/local/bin
pathadd /usr/local/sbin
pathadd ~/bin
```

This only adds directories to PATH if they exist (i.e. no bogus entries) and aren't already there.  Note: the pattern matching feature I use to see if the entry is already in PATH is only available in bash, not the original Bourne shell; if you want to use this with /bin/sh, that part'd need to be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice set of scripts that add path variables to the beginning or end of PATH depending on the ordering I want. The problem is OSX starts with /usr/local/bin after /usr/bin, which is exactly NOT what I want (being a brew user and all). So what I do is put a new copy of /usr/local/bin in front of everything else and use the following to remove all duplicates (and leave ordering in place).

```
MYPATH=$(echo $MYPATH|perl -F: -lape'$_=join":",grep!$s{$_}++,@F')
```

I found this on [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=522659). Like most perl, it looks like line noise to me so I have no idea how it works, but work it does!