# command working in command line but cannot generalize as function

Tags: bash

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178091/bash-path-is-caching-every-modification) question

@SiegeX gives a nice way of cleaning the bash PATH variable from
duplicate entries:

```
PATH=$(awk 'BEGIN{ORS=":";RS="[:\n]"}!a[$0]++' <<<"${PATH%:}")
```

this works well when I type it in the command line.
I tried using this in a bash function to be able to apply it to other variables:

```
function dupremove()
{
  ${1}=$(awk 'BEGIN{ORS=":";RS="[:\n]"}!a[$0]++' <<<"${1%:}")
}
```

but when I execute it it gives the error:

```
> dupremove PATH
bash: PATH=PATH:: command not found
```

Any idea on I can write the function?

Comment: @Rafe_Kettler it does not work with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (TM)

```
function dupremove
{
  eval path=\$$1
  export $1=$(awk 'BEGIN{ORS=":";RS="[:\n]"}!a[$0]++' <<< $path)
}
```